# Iphone Toolbar Icon with Dynamic Count

Tags: iphone

I've done a lot of googling and am at the end of my rope so here goes ... I just need to know if this is possible so I can design a series of screens for an Iphone app.

In my app you are able to leave comments on a certain topic, I would like an icon in the toolbar that displays a word bubble with a plus sign in the center when there are no existing comments and if there are existing comments I would like to display the same word bubble but instead of the plus I want to show the number of existing notes programatically.

Is this possible?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.  You populate a toolbar with UIBarButtonItem instances.  You can create one of these using

```
  -(id) initWithCustomView:(UIView *)myCustomView;
```

In your custom view, you can put any graphics you want, including a plus sign, or a subview with a UILabel that shows the number of comments.

When the status changes (comments are added or removed), you just need to create a new UIView and set the toolbar.customView to that view.